# How can I send JSON with $.ajax? (in the naive way, jQuery never sends JSON)

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to send via $.ajax / $.post (tried both methods) a **nested** json structure. The $.ajax I tried is this one:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/account/register/standard',
    method: 'post',
    data: datos,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(){
        console.log("llego al otro lado");
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log('nos jodimos');
    }
});
```

Where `datos` is a complex json structure.

If I get the data in the server endpoint, it arrives as a single-level object, with keys sintax as 'key[subkey]' for level-2 elements. This means, for the following structure:

```
datos = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: {
        d: 3,
        e: 4
    }
}
```

I don't get the same structure as a dictionary/map () in the server side. The data I get in the server-side is like this:

```
a=1&b=2&c[d]=3&c[e]=4
```

Such is the representation of the data as sent by the browser (Google Chrome, in my case).

So, jQuery does not truly treat my json as ... json.

OTOH, If I stringify the json value...

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/account/register/standard',
    method: 'post',
    data: JSON.stringify(datos),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(){
        console.log("llego al otro lado");
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log('nos jodimos');
    }
});
```

will send the JSON object, but in application/form-www-encoded, as well. So the data will be sent, and received, as a single k=v with k being a JSON representation and v being an empty string.

I need to receive, in my server side, a Content-Type = application/json, and a content being:

```
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":{"d":3,"e":4}}
```

How can I send a **true** JSON with jQuery?

Comment: can you post some relevant server side code

Comment: no. it is not related to server-side.

Comment: Please. I showed the browser sent content in the request, and showed that the format was not the one I was needing. From such perspective, whatever happens in server-side is absolutely irrelevant.

Comment: can u try setting contentType: "application/json",

Comment: Yep :D found it just now! Also found I needed to pass processData:false, in order to not get a querystring

Answer (score 0):

Found it :p. jQuery **always uses urlencoded data** by default. A `contentType` must be specified to `'application/json'` in the `$.ajax` call since the `dataType` option is related to the received data (response) and not the sent data.

Additionally, data is always processed and converted to url-encoded, unless you pass option `processData: false`.

In such way, the full code to perform a JSON request is:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/account/register/standard',
    method: 'post',
    data: JSON.stringify(datos),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    success: function(){
        console.log("llego al otro lado");
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log('nos jodimos');
    }
});
```

(Notice I kept the dataType option, since the response is also json)

Comment: not really, jQuery never converts it into query string unless you pass the data as object or array. Just stringify would be enough

Comment: A JavaScript object != to JSON

Comment: @Musa explain how useful is your comment